# What is the difference between std::trivially_copyable_v and std::is_pod_v (std::is_standard_layout && std::is_trivial_v)

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits

I was looking at the documentation for both of these type traits and I'm not sure what the difference is. I'm no language lawyer, but as far as I could tell, they are both valid for "memcpy-able" types.

Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No the terms cannot be used interchangeably. Both terms denote types that can be used with `memcpy`, and anything that's a POD is trivially copyable, but something that's trivially copyable is not necessarily POD.

In this simple example, you can see that `foo` is POD (and subsequently trivially copyable), while `bar` is not a POD, but is trivially copyable:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    int n;
};

struct bar
{
    int n = 4;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_pod<foo>() << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_trivially_copyable<foo>() << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_pod<bar>() << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_trivially_copyable<bar>() << "\n";
}
```

The output of the above is:

> true
> true
> false
> true

Both `foo` and `bar` can be used safely with [`memcpy`, whose documentation states](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy):

> If the objects are [...] not TriviallyCopyable, the behavior of memcpy is not specified and may be undefined.

Comment: Also helps to note that `std::is_pod` is for the [`PODType` named requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType), which requires a [`TrivialType`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType), which in turn requires a [`TriviallyCopyable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) type.